# OFFSET MATCH does not equal Function for Rotating Schedule

Tags: excel

I am creating a employee rotation schedule each one of the Assignments have different rotation lists, the formula in the attached sheet references a list and rotates the employees throughout the days. A problem I'm having is that the rotation only works if there are less than seven or more then seven employees in the rotation. What I'm looking for is a index match offset function which if there is a "" in the rotation list (I put that there so it rotates properly) the formula will offset to the value next in the rotation list.

Current formula used to lookup the value:

```
INDEX(B1:B9,MATCH(D1,IF(C1:C9<>"",B1:B9),0)+2,G6)
```

Its not returning the value I want.

The formula used to rotate through the employee lists:

```
OFFSET('Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2,MOD((ROW(A3)-D4),COUNTA('Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!A:A)-1),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. The formula does the trick just had to use CSE.

=IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E15,E15,1,'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$P$2:$P$37)=0,"No Work",IFNA(IF(MATCH(F15,H15:K15,0),INDEX($C$1:$C$9,MATCH(1,(H15<>$C$1:$C$9)*(I15<>$C$1:$C$9)*(J15<>$C$1:$C$9)*(K15<>$C$1:$C$9)*(G14<>$C$1:$C$9)*(G16<>$C$1:$C$9)*(F15<>$C$1:$C$9),0)),F15),F15))